# how to install kafka on hadoop multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to install the latest release of Kafka on my ubuntu Hadoop cluster that contains 1 master nodes and 4 data nodes.

Here are my questions:

1. Should kafka be installed on all the machines or only on NameNode machine?
2. What about zookeeper? Should it be installed on all the machines or only on NameNode machine?

Please share required document to install kafka and Zookeeper in a Hadoop 5 node cluster

Comment: which distribution you are using ?

Comment: i am using ubuntu and apache kafka